# I am 15 feet out

Tags: word-usage

In ["Man vs Wild"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_vs._Wild), [Bear Grylls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_Grylls) says:

> **I am 15 feet out.**

Actually he made a makeshift ladder to get down the waterfall safely. I know what this means. But for using it properly I looked up this usage, but it was about "money". Like:

> **I am $25 out.**

But is the use of "out" natural in the sentence used? **And can you give me a few examples using "out" in this manner?**

Comment: I'm sorry but that context is really quite poor.

Comment: "I am 15 feet out" means "I am 15 feet away from my goal"; this is unrelated to the money usage, which normally would reverse the word order: "I am out $25."

Comment: @Lambie, is the English used quite poor? Or is it not clear?

Comment: What is not clear is the the Bear Grylls citation.

Comment: "Context" means describing the situation in which something is said, often quoting several sentences prior to the one under consideration, and possibly a few sentences afterwards. Presumably, he was 15 feet away from something. It would help to know what that something was, and what significance the location 15 feet away had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage *to be [some amount of money] **out*** is a (significantly less common) alternative to colloquial *to be [some amount] **down***.

> [**down**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/down) (Cambridge Dictionary)
>    in or towards a lower level, a smaller amount, or a simpler state
>    Ex. *The Cavaliers were 20 points down (= losing by 20 points) at half-time.*

But it's worth pointing out that the ***down*** version is also used for other "quantifiable values" (often, but not always, in contexts where *lower = worse, higher = better*).

It's also worth noting that the ***out*** version is almost exclusively reserved for contexts where the "amount" is either ***money*** or something that can easily be seen as having a monetary value. Also, that it nearly always implies a money / value *that the subject previously had, and has now lost*.

---

Another usage difference is that Bear Grylls would have been *extremely* unlikely to say *I am **out** 15 feet* (in the more "literal" sense of ***out = away*** [from some initial starting position.

But for the ***out = without*** [having lost something] sense, the sequence *I'm **out** £10* is far more common than *I'm £10 **out*** - whereas *I'm **down** £10* and *I'm £10 **down*** are equally common alternatives.

Comment: So you mean that it's more common to say: "I'm $25 down" than "I'm out $25"?

Comment: Yes - although as noted by my edit just now, *I'm $25 down* and *I'm down $25* are equally "natural". But *I'm $25 out* isn't at all likely (it strikes me as rather "odd"), whereas *I'm out $25* is simply a less common expression (nothing actually "wrong" with it).

Comment: Fingers, is it natural to use "get down" with waterfall? Or should it be: "climb down" or maybe something else....

Comment: You simply don't deal with the out. Down is another meaning.

Comment: But is "get down" and "climb down" natural? (With "waterfall"?)

Comment: Get  down is fine. Otherwise, you have to use climb down or descend. The Brits use "get down" a lot like that: We still have 1,000 feet to get down, meaning: to go down.

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish - Most people don't climb down waterfalls, so it's hard to say what's "natural." I would probably say something like, "I am 100 feet down. I have 15 feet to go." But there is nothing wrong with what Bear Grylls said. (Besides, who wants to argue with Bear Grylls? Especially about grammar.)

Comment: @It's about English: As with choosing to use ***out*** instead of the more common *I'm £10 **down***, Bear Grylls's choice of preposition is perfectky okay - even though *in practice* most people would use ***down*** when describing how far they've moved from their starting point on a "descent" such as this. (Besides which, as J.R. points out, even if it *was* a bit flaky, who'd want to argue the toss with Bear Grylls? :) You could even (just about) say *I'm 2 days out* on the 2nd day of a *hiking* holiday (but probably not on the 2nd day of a *skiing* holiday, which doesn't "go" anywhere).

Answer (score 2):

***To be out some amount of money*** means: to be out of pocket some amount of money. To have spent some amount on something. Often, the full expression would be: to be out [of pocket] [amount].

***To be out some distance*** means: to still have to cover some distance before reaching an end point.

- Have you arrived yet? [a person asks another on a cell phone]
- No, we are still 15 miles out. [we still have 15 miles to go]
- How far have you gone? [one person asks another on a cell phone]
- We are 15 miles out. [We  have gone 15 miles from some original point]

It is used when communicating with someone, say, over a radio, telephone, etc. about reaching a destination. It can also mean to have traveled a certain distance as well. So, really, a specific context is needed.

Summary: out from x, can be how far you have traveled or how far you still have to go. In that sense, Fumble Fingers is right.

Those are both idiomatic. Both are used very commonly in English.

Comment: So what can be a better way to describe the context? I mean what can I use to describe "climbing down" a waterfall, can't "get down" be used?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish You need to provide the link to the text. I don't even know who that is. But I understand the sentence. I have given you the idiomatic usage for both.

Comment: I disagree that *To be out some distance means: to still have to cover some distance before reaching an end point*. This would very rarely be the intended sense - it would almost always mean *to have **traveled** [that distance] **from a starting position***. And on the rare occasions it *did* mean *to be [that distance] away from a destination*, the preposition would almost always come *after* the distance (i.e. - we're talking about an uncommon sense of *To be some distance **out***).

Comment: And is the use of "get down" natural? Or should it be "climb down", or something else?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, my example is completely idiomatic. To be out [25 miles] means: we still have 25 miles to cover before getting to [some place]. A pilot might say that: "We're 100 miles out. Over."  to a radio tower.

Comment: As given in my example, when communicating with another person, it is about distance to destination OR distance traveled from some point.It can be either, depending on context.

Comment: When talking about how far we are from a destination, natives will often use _away_; for example: _How far are you from Grandma's house?_ (Answer: _We are 20 miles away;_ or: _We are 30 minutes away_). But you are absolutely correct when you say that _out_ is also used: _We are 30 kilometers out._ One other note: using _out_ in this context seems to have more of an "official" tone when it comes to navigation – I think I'd be more likely to hear it from the captain of a boat than from a grandson in his car. (It sounds like something my dad might say – but he served in the Coast Guard.)

Comment: @Lambie: Sure - a pilot *might* say  "We're 100 miles out" with that meaning. But only when speaking to air traffic control at his *destination*, and even then I suggest he might be more likely to say ***away*** or ***off***. But if speaking to a controller based at his *takeoff* airport, the natural meaning to infer there would be *distance from **starting position***, not destination.

Comment: @FumbleFingers out can be either. It depends on context.